# Executing the sql queries on oracle DB using cx_Oracle in python throws error

Tags: python, python-2.7, cx-oracle

Error:

```
DPI-1047: 32-bit Oracle Client library cannot be loaded: "The specified module could not be found"
```

Python:

```
Python 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:19:30) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
```

I have installed 64 bit python but when I type python in my command prompt, it shows python application is of 32 bit.

Question:

I am trying to run the SQL queries on a oracle Database residing on a remote server. I have used the below two methods to connect to the database and received the error mentioned above.

```
## Method 1
ip='10.8.183.137'
port=1522
SID='DB10'
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(ip, port, SID)
log.info('dsn_tns: ' + dsn_tns)
db = cx_Oracle.connect('sys', 'OraPasswd01', dsn_tns)

##Method 2
dbconn = cx_Oracle.connect(connstr, mode=cx_Oracle.SYSDBA);
```

Method#2 works if I copy the script on the virtual server and run it, I want to implement this from my PC.

Comment: Do you have an Oracle client installed on your PC? cx_Oracle requires an Oracle client.

Comment: Yeah it is on both my PC and the server.

Comment: Dig around and find out why you have 32-bit python installed.  Where is it?  Can you force the 64-bit python to be used (perhaps by changing PATH)?  Alternatively, install the 32-bit Instant Client.

Answer (score 0):

This error come when your Oracle Client is not installed or LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not set where libclntsh.so is present.

if you have Oracle client installed then search for libclntsh.so and set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH as

"export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/app/bds/parcels/ORACLE_INSTANT_CLIENT/instantclient_11_2:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"

Check following link for more details for Oracle client installation: oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#linux